# taskkill not working: it says there are no matching process running

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, taskkill

I have 4 batch files.
master.bat starts all the other 3 batch files.

```
master.bat

@ECHO OFF
TITLE "MasterBatch"
start "mainJS" "mainJS.bat"
timeout /t 1
start "firefoxBatch" "firefoxStart.bat"
timeout /t 1

start "browserCheckBatch" "browserCheck.bat"
timeout /t 1
ECHO "4"
```

mainJS.bat file starts the main.js file which is node.js file

```
mainJS.bat

@ECHO OFF

node main.js
```

browserCheck.bat file terminates all the other batchfiles when firefox is terminated.

```
browserCheck.bat

@ECHO OFF

timeout /t 1

:LOOP
tasklist | find /i "firefox.exe" >nul 2>&1
IF errorlevel 1 (
    GOTO CONTINUE
)   ELSE (
    ECHO firefox still running
    timeout /T 5 /Nobreak
    GOTO LOOP
)

:CONTINUE
ECHO firefox closed

taskkill /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq  mainJS"
ECHO %mainJSTitle%
taskkill /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq  MasterBatch"
taskkill /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq  firefoxBatch"
```

But the problem is browsercheck.bat doesn't terminate mainJS batchfile. I've looked into the problem and the windows automatically renames my mainJS batchfile window title into mainJS - mainJS.bat and this seems to make it impossible for my browsercheck.bat to close the mainJS.bat file. It doesn't happen to other batch files. What should I do?

Comment: `taskkill /FI "WindowTitle eq mainJS*"`?

Answer (score 0):

If we start a .cmd or .bat file without a Title, it is difficult to distinguish its function

[image]

We are encouraged to add a Title but that may then sometimes be varied by the calling method

[image]

To ensure a .bat or .CMD will itself report the same Title each time
[image]

then get into the habit of using a first line like

```
@ECHO OFF & Title MainJS
```

Generally avoid a "Long Phrase With Spaces" it easier if it is a short accurate Mnemonic.